# "Upsampling data" of data in Python

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science

I'm newish to Python and brand new to data-science.

I've got a large data set that I've been using supervised machine learning (CART with scikit-learn) to classify. I'm using pandas data-frames, for the most part, to operate on the data. The data looks like this:

```
| F00 F01 F02 F03 ... C0 |
| ... .. .. ... ... .....|
| FN0 FN1 FN2 FN3... CN  |
```

where Fij is the j'th feature of the i'th row, and Ck is the true class of that row/instance.

The problem is one of the 6 classes has a much larger proportion of the training samples. I've looked up up-sampling, but this seems to refer to the case of (unsurprisingly) sampling the data randomly as you would do with an extremely large data set.

What I want is upscale rather than upsample - that is, copy with replacement random instances of the minority classes, adding them into the dataset until the sizes of all classes match.

I've had no luck using pandas to do this so far, I was wondering if you might be able to help?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please provide a small example dataset to work with - not just a formal specification - along with expected output.  That makes it much easier to provide a concrete solution.  Even if your actual data are quite large, you should still be able to generate a [mcve] to demonstrate the issue you have.

Comment: +1 for the comment above; what you are looking for is techniques for class imbalance (start by googling it) - http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ , http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/

Comment: thanks! Sorry, will do in future posts

Comment: Why not make the changes here instead of wait for a future post?  You can edit your original post.

Comment: Truthfully because it is not my data to put online, but I understand why I should put it up

Answer (score 1):

Original asker here:

For anyone interested, I did the following using the imblearn package:

```
from imblearn.over_sampling import RandomOverSampler, SMOTE, ADASY

def organize_data(data, upsample=False, upmethod = None): # entire organizing, cleaning data function

...

if upsample:
        upsampler = upmethod()
        features, true_class = upsampler.fit_sample(features, true_class)
```

Just using RandomOverSampler as a naive approach to expanding my minority classes (as was appropriate with my data).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you wish to deal with "learning from an unbalanced data set" issue.

There are many ways you can deal with this (this  [article](https://machinelearningmastery.com/tactics-to-combat-imbalanced-classes-in-your-machine-learning-dataset/)  gives an overview on several ways to tackle this issue)

I believe that [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedShuffleSplit.html) will help you solve this.